# Loading a png resource in wpf assembly fails

Tags: wpf, resources

For hours I've been attempting to load a PNG-file located inside the assembly where it will be loaded (WPF UserControl), without any success.
The PNG file, "folder.png" is now in the project root directory. Inside the VS2015 project the file is also visible as a project root member. The Build Action for the file is Resource (Do not copy).

Now the simple test code (normally the image files will be in some subfolder of the project):

```
 Uri pngUri = new Uri(@"folder.png", UriKind.Relative);
 BitmapImage pleaseWork = new BitmapImage(pngUri);
```

All I see is that the `file could not be located.`  Setting a breakpoint in Debug configuration after the Uri construction, most of the properties of the `pngUri` object shows:

> System.InvalidOperationException.

After the `BitmapImage` construction the `pleaseWork` object shows me:

> System.FileNotFoundException

I tried constructing the `Uri` object many different ways with no success.

By the way, ILSpy found the PNG-file correctly under `MyAssembly.g.resources` as 'folder.png' entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
var pngUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/folder.png");
var pleaseWork = new BitmapImage(pngUri);
```

If the file is in a different assembly, you'll have to add the assembly name to the Pack URI:

```
var pngUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/folder.png");
```

where `ReferencedAssembly` has to be replaced by the actual assembly name.

Comment: The result is now: Unknown Uri-prefix. BTW: Is application a placeholder? I used it as placeholder and entered there my assembly name.... ooops, that maybe wrong... will test it now.

Comment: With your code "File 'folder.png' not found" appears. So "pack://application:" is correct, but the image is not found...

Comment: Not the file couldn't be found... the resource 'folder.png' couldn't be found.

Comment: The file has to be added to the VS project, at the top level, and its Build Action has to be set Resource (but apparently you already did that). It has no relation to Resources.resx.

Comment: Yep. It's added to the top level and Build Action is set to Resource. I rebuilded the assembly meanwhile 100 times (it feels so)...

Comment: Is it in a different assembly than the application?

Comment: Both the code and the image are inside the same assembly i'm testing. The assembly is called by another application.

Comment: Then use a Pack URI with assembly name. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Clemens! It works!!! (its so easy.... but the uri is a little bit 'ugly'.. i will never find this solution...).